# How can you understand curl of electric field illustratively?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, rotation, dipole

Considering the curl of the electric field of an electric dipole, this will be zero in absence of magnetic effects which is clear to me. I watched a video by 3Blue1Brown (some time ago) who explained the curl of an electric field illustratively in terms of a vector field. Considering a point in the electric field of an electric dipole, the field lines on one side will be closer (stronger electric field) than on the other side thus creating a 'rotation' around that point, however, the curl of the electric field is clearly zero. How is this the case? Does the understanding of curl as a 'rotation' around a point apply to an electric dipole? I understand that the field lines form closed loops that include the dipole itself thus introducing a singularity breaking down this method completely, but when can this method of 'rotation' be applied to electromagnetism and spicifically rotation?

Comment: If you can convince yourself that any closed contour integral $\oint \mathbf E \cdot d\ell $  of the electric field $\mathbf E = \frac{\mathbf r^0}{r^2} $ of a single point source is zero then just apply the principle of superposition and consider a *dipole* as the sum of two monopoles of opposing sign. The "curl" is just the closed contour integral per unit enclosed area.

Comment: If you do not want to consider field of individual point-charges, note that field from electric dipole should really contain a delta function. It is normally omitted, e.g. in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment, but it is precisely for your type of questions that it becomes important. That delta function spike will effectively 'undo' the rotation you observe in the commonly presented field lines